# Coupled PDE on cylinder

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following system on a noncompact cylinder $(\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z})\times[0,1)$ with coordinates $(x,t)$:

$$\partial_tf(x,t)=-\partial_xg(x,t)$$
$$\partial_tg(x,t)=\partial_xf(x,t)$$
$$g(x,0)=0$$
$$f(x,0)=F(x)$$

**Is there some $F(x)$ as the initial condition such that the system has no solution?** I seem to be going on a wild goose chase, where the goose might not exist.

For example, $F(x)=\sin(x)$ doesn't help since there is a solution:

$$f(x,t)=\sin(x)\cosh(t)$$
$$g(x,t)=\cos(x)\sinh(t)$$

Comment: Have you tried to prove that the complex function on $z=x+it$ satisfying the boundary condition does not exist for some $F(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the solution using the Laplace transform but a direct
approach is also possible. We have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{t}f(x,t) &=&-\partial _{x}g(x,t) \\
\partial _{t}g(x,t) &=&\partial _{x}f(x,t)
\end{eqnarray*}

$$
\partial _{t}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
f(t) \\
g(t)
\end{array}
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) \partial _{x}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
f(t) \\
g(t)
\end{array}
\right) =B\left(
\begin{array}{c}
f(t) \\
g(t)
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Now
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
f(t) \\
g(t)
\end{array}
\right) =\exp [Bt]\left(
\begin{array}{c}
f(0) \\
g(0)
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Here we have
$$
B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) \partial _{x},\;B^{2}=-\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) (\partial _{x})^{2},\;B^{3}=-\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) (\partial _{x})^{3},\cdots
$$
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
\exp [Bt] &=&\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) +\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) (t\partial _{x})-\frac{1}{2!}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) (t\partial _{x})^{2}-\frac{1}{3!}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) (t\partial _{x})^{3}\cdots  \\
&=&\cos (t\partial _{x})\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) +\sin (t\partial _{x})\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
With the given initial conditions
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
f(t) \\
g(t)
\end{array}
\right) =\left\{ \cos (t\partial _{x})\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) +\sin (t\partial _{x})\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) \right\} \left(
\begin{array}{c}
F \\
0
\end{array}
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\cos (t\partial _{x})F \\
\sin (t\partial _{x})F
\end{array}%
\right)
$$
We can write
$$
f(x,t)+ig(x,t)=\exp [it\partial _{x}]F(x)=F(x+it)
$$
provided $F(x)$ has an analytic continuation into the complex plane.